# Getting the error "fatal: cannot run .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory" when trying to execute git commit. The pre-commit file is there

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, vscode-devcontainer

### My Situation

I've got a pre-commit hook installed within the .git/hooks directory of my project. However, whenever I try to perform a `git commit -m "whatever"` for a commit, I just get an error message saying the pre-commit file doesn't exist. The file definitely exists. If I remove the file, commits happen just fine again, but for this project I do need to have a pre-commit hook in place before committing to the repo.

### My Environment

I'm running inside of a Visual Studio Code (VSCode) devcontainer. The devcontainer is using WSL-backed (Windows Subsystem for Linux) Docker with a container built from `python:3.10-slim-bullseye`.

#### Host OS

```
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise
Version: 10.0.22621 Build 22621
```

#### VSCode

```
Version: 1.77.3 (system setup)
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No
```

#### Devcontainer

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4fb27f5c92e0 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue           
Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l

$ git --version                                                           
git version 2.30.2
```

### What I've tried

As an example, here is the output of running a `git commit` command. The commit will fail and not take place as a result of this error.

```
$ git commit -m "arbitrary git commit message"
fatal: cannot run .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory
```

I thought that maybe there was some issue within the pre-commit file that was causing the issue, so I stripped the file down to the bones, to just run an `echo "test"` command. But even that doesn't work (again, the file also definitely exists, so there *is* such a file or directory, Linux/Git!)

```
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit               
#!/bin/bash

echo "test"
```

Additionally, here are the permissions for the file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me root 816 Sep 28 17:22 .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

where I am `me`. This isn't a problem with the contents of the pre-commit file, as the pre-commit file itself is quite simple. This is an issue with Git being able to actually read/execute the file as I understand it.

I tried Googling around or looking at other SO posts about pre-commit hooks running into this issue, but most (all?) of those issues are issues within the pre-commit hook's code itself, not in running the pre-commit hook straight-up.

#### Notably, pre-commit works outside of devcontainer

If I were to use my host git and try to do a commit, the pre-commit hook will run (though it'll run into issues since my host doesn't have the software the pre-commit hook is attempting to use, that stuff is installed within the devcontainer). It's *only* an issue within the devcontainer.

### What I expect to happen

I expect my `pre-commit` hook file to execute whenever I execute `git commit`.

Comment: Can you try to run `.git/hooks/pre-commit` directly? Can you [edit] the question and show us the text output of `cat -v .git/hooks/pre-commit` ? I suspect the file has DOS end-of-lines (CR+LF) instead of Unix (just LF).

Comment: Oh no, I feel dumb. That was indeed the problem, the EoL's were CRLF and not LF. Thank you so much! I wish that it had produced a more helpful error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on `phd`'s comment, I was asked to try running the script directly, which was revealing of the problem.

```
$ .git/hooks/pre-commit       
zsh: .git/hooks/pre-commit: bad interpreter: /bin/bash^M: no such file or directory
```

Additionally, I was asked to provide the output of `cat -v` of the file.

```
$ cat -v .git/hooks/pre-commit
#!/bin/bash^M
^M
echo "test"^M
```

Which also highlights the problem.

The issue was with the End of Line character(s). In *nix (in this case, Linux), line-ending character(s) are the `\n` or Line Feed (LF) character. In Windows, the line-ending character(s) are `\r\n`, or the Carriage Return (CR) and Line Feed (LF) characters (oft abbreviated as CRLF).

To fix the issue, I was able to use VScode to change the line ending characters by clicking on the line ending button on the bottom bar and changing it from CRLF to LF.

[Image showing the file now showing LF as the line ending characters rather than the CRLF which it had previously shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpRrA.png)

Another way I could have done this is by using the command line to remove those pesky CR's. Something like the below, perhaps (untested) (also caveat if the script had `\r` in it for some other purpose like not at the end of a line it might ruin that):

```
cat .git/hooks/pre-commit | tr -d '\r' > .git/hooks/pre-commit.tmp && mv .git/hooks/pre-commit.tmp .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Comment: `cat .git/hooks/pre-commit | … > .git/hooks/pre-commit` I'd be very afraid to `cat` a file and at the same time redirects to it. If the shell decides 1st do redirection the file will be truncated to zero length. My advice is to do `cat .git/hooks/pre-commit | tr -d '\r' > .git/hooks/pre-commit.tmp && mv .git/hooks/pre-commit.tmp .git/hooks/pre-commit`

Comment: Fair enough. I've edited the answer with that one-liner instead! Thanks